# Call to undefined method stdClass::notify()

Tags: php, laravel

FatalThrowableError in MyController
Call to undefined method stdClass::notify()

laravel notify() undefined method. how to solved it....help me..

Controller file:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Mail;
use Apps\User;
use App\Notifications\InvoicePaid;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
  public function EmailNotify(){
  $user = DB::table('users')->where('id',2)->first();
  $urlData = DB::table('url')->where('id',2)->first();

  $user->notify(new InvoicePaid($urlData));

 }
}
```

app/Notifications/InvoicePaid.php

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class InvoicePaid extends Notification
{
 use Queueable;
 protected $toto;

public function __construct($toturial)
{
    $this->toto=$toturial;
}

public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

To use the `notify` method you need to add the `Notifiable` trait to your class.

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
    use \Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

    //...
}
```

If you don't want to use the `Notifiable` trait you can use the `Notification` facade.

```
Notification::send($users, new InvoicePaid($invoice));
```

More details are available [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#sending-notifications). Laracasts also have a video on it. [Watch it here](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/9).